# Overflow in DataTable when the float data in a column has too many digits after comma

Tags: .net, oracle, datatable, overflow

I'm getting data from `Oracle DB` to a `DataTable` via `OracleDataAdapter`.
But when the `Oracle Number` `column` in a `row` has too many digits in DB i get a System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow exception.
How can i handle this situation?

Regards.

Comment: What .NET type is the `DataTable` column for the value, and what is the Oracle type?

Answer (score 1):

`Number` type in Oracle may have up to 38 decimal digits. If you have any means of control on the target data structure, you should use `float` for this field.

By the way, you haven't mentioned, what programming language you are using.

Comment: the only tag this question had, when I asked was oracle.

Comment: It's less then 38 digits. For example: 25.2836319018405 And yes it's .Net C#

Comment: And what type is variable on C# side?

Comment: Does the partial call stack answer the question?    at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.DecimalConv.GetDecimal(IntPtr numCtx)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)

Comment: Well, for `Int32` value range is -2^31 - +2^31, which gives us 10 decimal digits (9, to be on a safer side). It's a big chance you get an overflow when importing from Oracle `number` type with it's 38 digits...